# Run multiple R scripts in parallel with command line arguments

Tags: r, parallel-processing, batch-processing, bioinformatics

I have an R script that performs analysis on one chromosome. I want to run this script repeatedly for each chromosome (1-22, X and Y). Right now I have the script set up to accept one argument from command line, the chromosome number. I want to submit multiple jobs to my server in parallel since analysis for one chromosome takes a few hours. After playing around with some options and googling everything, I'm still not sure what the best option is as I've never submitted jobs in parallel to a server (Sun Grid Engine server). I looked into `GNU parallel` but I'm not sure how to use it or if it even runs for R scripts. Maybe throw everything in a shell script and submit that to the server? This is a pretty basic question, but any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/ pi.dk/1 pi.dk/4

Comment: Show a code example of how you do now.

Comment: Yes I have that window open right now actually. So this approach will work with R scripts? Right now I don't really have anything I just know I can run my script with an argument like `Rscript plot_LRR_BAF_chromosome_parallel <chromNumber>`

Comment: Turn your code into a function that accepts an argument, and use R's `parallel` package.

Answer (score 0):

```
parallel Rscript plot_LRR_BAF_chromosome_parallel ::: {1..22} X Y
```

Comment: This command seems to work normally when called from command line. I'm trying to submit it to the server, but when I call it from within a .sh script or directly from `qsub <options> parallel Rscript plot_LRR_BAF_chromosome_parallel ::: {1..22} X Y` It says `Unable to read script file because of error: error opening parallel: No such file or directory`. Any ideas?

Comment: Show an example of how you normally qsub jobs.

Answer (score 0):

using GNU **make** with option `-j` , replace `__CHROM__` in your R script with the chromosome name.

```
chroms=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

define method1

$$(addsuffix .out,$(1)) : script.R
    cat $$< | sed 's/__CHROM__/$(1)/g' | R --nosave > $$@

endef

all: $(addsuffix .out,$(chroms))

$(foreach C, $(chroms),$(eval $(call method1, $(C) )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rstudio has a very reliable, easy and intuitive way of running parallel scripts called **Background jobs**. The following [link](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/tools/jobs.html) explains how to use it, but in summary, everytime you run a script, it runs in paralel, using multiple cores and it usually goes much faster (if the CPU and RAM are not super busy). There are two ways to use Background Jobs, the manual and the scripted:

1. The manual way: you just open the *background job* and select the script and the working directory. Then you can choose to save the global environment or not. If your script already exports or save the objects at local, then do not worry about that. You can run the script with, for example, chromosomes 1 to 7, then you change the values from 8 to 15 save the script and run background job, and the third script from 16 to 22. This way you can run it in paralel but please, check that CPU or RAM do not run at values too close to 100%.
2. The scripted way: you can use [JobRunScript](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/jobRunScript.html) to create background jobs with code. Therefore you can automate the changes you want from the scripts.